# preg_match не видит большую букву в фамилии в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

При проверке фамилии с большой буквы выводит "false", хотя регулярное выражение проверено на regex101.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$str = "Петров";
$pattern = "/^([А-Я]{1}[а-я]{1,})?$/";



 if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches) === true) {
//print_r($matches);

 echo '<script>';
 echo ' alert("true!!!");';  
 echo '</script>';

} else {
//print_r($matches);

 echo '<script>';
 echo ' alert("false!!!");';  
 echo '</script>';

 }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На regex101.com всё работает. У Вас кодировка какая в файле? Вообще короче так: /^([А-Я][а-я]+)?$/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте флаг `u` в конце

```
"/^([А-Я]{1}[а-я]{1,})?$/u"
```

для юникода. Возможно в этом дело

---

также надо заменить `true` на `1` - см. [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php).

> Функция preg_match() возвращает 1, если параметр pattern соответствует переданному параметру subject, 0 если нет или false в случае возникновения ошибки.

Comment: не помогает. https://fastpic.org/fullview/120/2022/1103/_2c792f7b44dd6c54f2be3396557375a8.jpg.html

Comment: Обнаружена угроза.......)) eset ругается на вирус........... вообще всё помогает https://onlinephp.io/c/bb0eb

Comment: вы сделали так как указано в ответе, без отсебятины?

Comment: @csharperbegin плюс ещё как подсказали - надо true на 1 заменить.... т.к. это возвращает функция

Comment: спасибо, /u помогло))) часа 2 убил, чтобы понять что не работает

Answer (score 0):

Кроме предложенного @Алексей Шиманский `u` еще нужно заменить `true` на `1` - см. [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php). Функция `preg_match() возвращает 1, если параметр pattern соответствует переданному параметру subject, 0 если нет или false в случае возникновения ошибки`.
Немного укоротил regex, `{1}` и `{1,}` избыточны.

```
$str = "Петров";
$pattern = "/^[А-Я][а-я]+$/u";



if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches) === 1) {
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    print("Не совпало");
}
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Петров
)
```

Comment: Тогда я дополню свой ответ) потому что он неполный)